# Facebook retrieving leads by page_id and page access token without form or ad_group ids

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, backend, integration

I want to integrate facebook leads in our fb CRM what we want is to make exactly what Zapier does.
User subscribe his page => can import the leads of this page and choosing form is optional => subscribe the webhook

I did all of this, but I'm stuck in how to make the `form` optional as all APIs of retrieving leads contains `form_id` or `ad_group_id`, here is the docs link that I'm follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving/

I now can retrieve pages, forms, leads, subscribe in webhook but can't get leads of a page without using specific form, I mean get all leads in this page

Comment: So get the page's forms first, and then get the leads for each of those forms?

Comment: @CBroe this is what I actually did but I think this isn't suit performance wise, we have pages that contains tens of forms, sending tens of http requests to handle one end point I think isn't the best solution so I'm asking if there is a way to get all of them from one api call that I didn't find during my search

Comment: Not that I know of, no.